# tikzfillbetween Ignoring Control Points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I have a simple question. I am creating a schematic drawing in TikZ without using the axis feature where I need to shade a region between a L-shape (part of a rectangle) and a spline generated using control points. However, the tikzfillbetween command completely ignores the control points of the spline and treats it as a straight line between its endpoints. Please let me know how I can fix it. I have included my code and attached the (undesired) output.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sid

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11.0in, left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in, includefoot]{geometry}               
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}enter image description here
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, black, name path=rect1] (0,4) -- (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[thick, black, name path=rect2] (4,0) -- (12,0) -- (12,4) -- (0,4);
\draw[thick, black, name path=topo] (0,4) .. controls (2.5,2.5) and (1.5,0)  .. (4,0);
\tikzfillbetween[of=rect1 and topo]{fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5,pattern=north east lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage} 
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Undesired Output]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11.0in, 
            margin=1.25in, 
            includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle ++ (12,4);
\draw[thick, fill opacity=0.5,
      pattern=north east lines] (0,0) -- (0,4) .. controls (2.5,2.5) and (1.5,0)  .. (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

From Your preamble I delete all not relevant packages and libraries for this solution. As you can see, it not use `\tikzfillbetween` but simple `fill`.

[image]

With use of the `\tikzfillbetween` library you need to give names only to two paths, for example `A` which is on bottom of rectangle, and `B` which is named of curve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11.0in, 
            margin=1.25in, 
            includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle ++ (12,4);
\path[name path=A] (0,0) -- (12,0);  % <---
\draw[thick, name path=B] (0,4) .. controls (2.5,2.5) and (1.5,0) .. (4,0); % <---
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B] {fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5, pattern=north east lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

result is the same as before.

Comment: Thank you so much!